# Data View Web Part Calculated Column Total (Sum)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, data-view-web-part

I have created a data view web part (grouped based on different criteria). I added a footer and I would like to generate a total for all the columns.

I was able to calculate a total for basic columns (number columns). However, when I tried to calculate total for a calculated column, I got an incorrect value "NaN":

[image: Click here to view an image of the code and design.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when I was enhancing our databases. Sharepoint never convert a blank item into "zero" that's why when you total the column, it displays "Nan". You have to manually/automatically put zero on blanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need is format your xslt formula as a number. Try 'format-number' function or you can use XPath Expression Builder which is available in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Dedek,

I added 'format-number' function:
**<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($nodeset/@ows_Pallets_x0020_On_x0020_Hand), '#,#0;-#,#0')"/>**

This returned a blank.

Since the orginal values were displayed as (e.g.) "float;#17115.00000", I had changed the <td> code to:
**<xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-after(@ows_Pallets_x0020_On_x0020_Hand,';#'),'#,##0;-#,##0')" />**

Therefore, I also tried the following code for the total:
**<xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-after(sum($nodeset/@ows_Pallets_x0020_On_x0020_Hand),';#'), '#,#0;-#,#0')"/>**

Also retruned a blank.

Comment: @ssw, Plz, update yr main post

Answer (score -1):

First, why do you duplicate what is provided by Sharepoint OOTB?

Select DVWP (DataViewWebPart visual web part) on design surface and on ribbon's "ListView Tools" --> "Design" tag --< check "Totals row"

After that you can select a produced total (digit) --> Split (to show both Design and Code in parallel) --> select on ribbon "Design" --> "Customize XSLT" tab (under "Actions" group) --> "Customize Item"

This will highlight you the correct XSL code part for a total which is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($Rows/@FieldID)" />
```

While your code produces incorrect results for non-computed field:

```
21.724
786
23.204
-------
45.714
```

Comment: "Totals Row" does not exist for a DataViewWebPart, only for an XsltListViewWebPart.